# Return data even if no record present sql server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have table called students, and I would get record even if data is not present for a particular course , in particular year.

Here is my data :

```
CREATE TABLE students ([Year] int,
                       Course varchar(50),
                       [Number of students] int);

INSERT INTO students
VALUES (2018, 'Maths ', 10),
       (2019, 'Maths', 15),
       (2018, 'Economics', 8),
       (2018, 'Social Studies', 3),
       (2019, 'Social Studies', 4),
       (2018, 'Science', 7);
```

How to get output like this :

```
Year    Course  Students
2018    Maths   10
2019    Maths   15
2018    Economics   8
2019    Economics   0
2018    Social Studies  3
2019    Social Studies  4
2018    Science 7
2019    Science 0
```

Please I don’t want to write code values manually if using where clause , example, where course in (‘economics ‘,’maths’ ). Would like to use variables instead in SQL server.

Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for trying to post sample data as DDL and DML, but please do check the SQL is valid first. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This gets you the results you want, however, with a large table the `DISTINCT` is likely to get expensive:

```
SELECT Y.[Year],
       C.Course,
       ISNULL(S.[Number of students],0) AS [Number of students]
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT [Year] FROM dbo.students) Y
     CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT Course FROM dbo.students) C
     LEFT JOIN dbo.students S ON Y.[Year] = S.[Year]
                             AND C.Course = S.Course;
```

Ideally you should have a separate table with your Year and Course data, and then the query can be "shortened" to:

```
SELECT Y.[Year],
       C.Course,
       ISNULL(S.[Number of students],0) AS [Number of students]
FROM dbo.Years Y
     CROSS JOIN dbo.Courses C
     LEFT JOIN dbo.students S ON Y.[Year] = S.[Year]
                             AND C.Course = S.Course;
```

Comment: Thanks @TimBiegeleisen. Your's is more a less the same as mine as well, with the exception of using literal values for values.

Comment: That's perfect! Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

You may join with calendar tables:

```
WITH years AS (
    SELECT 2018 AS Year UNION ALL
    SELECT 2019
),
courses AS (
    SELECT 'Maths' AS Course UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Economics' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Social Studies' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Science'
)

SELECT
    y.Year,
    c.Course,
    COALESCE(s.Students, 0) AS Students
FROM year y
CROSS JOIN courses c
LEFT JOIN Students s
    ON s.Year = y.Year AND s.Course = c.Course;
```

Comment: I have to do this for each and every year, going forward and backward , so don't want to hard code years like 2016, 2017, 2018 etc. But thanks for this as well

Comment: @SindhuB Ideally you should maintain tables for the year and course.  Both of the answers given are really just workarounds.